# AudioKit macOS HelloWorld makes no sound with Bluetooth speaker

Tags: macos, avfoundation, audiokit

I am running the Hello World example from AudioKit-macOS-4.7.2 using macOS Mojave 10.14.5 on a Mac mini (2018).

When running the example using the inbuilt speaker, sound is heard, all is well.

When running the example with a UE BOOM 2 bluetooth speaker connected, no sound is heard and I get the following output:

```
2019-07-12 10:09:19.615436+0100 HelloWorld[1874:44088] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:958:IOWorkLoop:  HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: the server failed to start, Error: 0xE00002D6
```

I can play iTunes through all speakers fine.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Edit: If AudioKit uses AVAudioPlayerNode then I suspect this is due to the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092434/avaudioplayer-play-works-but-avaudioplayernode-play-crashes).

Comment: Interesting, when I use AirPods, also a Bluetooth device, I get the same results (no sound) with a different error:  [AudioHAL_Client] HALB_IOThread.cpp:251:_Start:  HALB_IOThread::_Start: there already is a thread

Comment: I thought the problem might have to do with Hello World's "Capabilities" - I went to "Signing & Capabilites" and added "App Sandbox" and there was the Bluetooth checkbox, so I checked it. Then I ran the project and now it makes sound! Except wait, no, the sound is coming from the MacBook speakers, not my AirPods. So, it didn't solve anything, but might give someone else a clue.

Comment: It looks AVAudioSession might have only started supporting bluetooth output in Catalina, from the sidebar here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/port