# AVAudioPlayer.play() works but AVAudioPlayerNode.play() fails

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I have the following Swift playground code that plays an audio file using AVAudioPlayerNode.

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
    print("Exception thrown: \(exception)")
}

var filePath = "/Users/fractor/Desktop/TestFile.mp3"
let file : AVAudioFile
do {
    file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    throw error
}

let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
audioEngine.attach(playerNode)
audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: file.processingFormat);

do {
    try audioEngine.start()
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    throw error
}

playerNode.scheduleFile(file, at: nil){}
playerNode.play();
```

This works fine on my mac mini when using the inbuilt speaker or when connected to a UE WONDERBOOM bluetooth speaker. However it crashes when connected to a UE BOOM 2 bluetooth speaker.

Using `AVAudioPlayer` works fine with all speakers I have tried including the UE BOOM 2.

The exception message is "player started when engine not running" however inserting print commands shows that the engine is running prior to `playerNode.play()` being called.

Here's (part of) the stack trace.

[image: Stack trace]

What does EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION indicate in this case?

To remove the possibility of erroneous behaviour being introduced due to using a Swift playground, I have also created a Swift macOS Cocoa app. Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let filePath = "/Users/fractor/Desktop/TestFile.mp3"
    var file : AVAudioFile?
    var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    var playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        audioEngine.attach(playerNode)
        audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: file!.processingFormat);

        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        playerNode.scheduleFile(file!, at: nil){}

        print("audioEngine.isRunning = \(audioEngine.isRunning)");
        playerNode.play();
        print("playerNode.isPlaying = \(playerNode.isPlaying)");
    }
}
```

This fails to play when connected to the UE BOOM 2 speaker with the following errors:

```
2019-07-23 13:32:50.784444+0100 AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest[1757:29297] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:958:IOWorkLoop:  HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: the server failed to start, Error: 0xE00002D6
2019-07-23 13:32:51.696089+0100 AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest[1757:29249] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): player started when engine not running
2019-07-23 13:32:53.815222+0100 AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest[1757:29448] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:958:IOWorkLoop:  HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: the server failed to start, Error: 0xE00002D6
```

Again this works fine with the WONDERBOOM speaker and the inbuilt speaker.

I manage to get an exception trace if I call `play` on a background thread using the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print("audioEngine.isRunning = \(self.audioEngine.isRunning)");
    self.playerNode.play();
    print("playerNode.isPlaying = \(self.playerNode.isPlaying)");
}
```

The full output being:

```
audioEngine.isRunning = true
2019-07-24 12:25:38.710647+0100 AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest[1852:21353] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:958:IOWorkLoop:  HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: the server failed to start, Error: 0xE00002D6
2019-07-24 12:25:40.717683+0100 AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest[1852:21340] [General] An uncaught exception was raised
2019-07-24 12:25:40.717738+0100 AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest[1852:21340] [General] player started when engine not running
2019-07-24 12:25:40.717865+0100 AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest[1852:21340] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2d017cfd __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff576bea17 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2d032a1a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff291f2304 _Z19AVAE_RaiseExceptionP8NSStringz + 156
    4   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff29247d8c _ZN21AVAudioPlayerNodeImpl9StartImplEP11AVAudioTime + 1282
    5   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff29246b48 -[AVAudioPlayerNode play] + 75
    6   AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest          0x0000000100002924 $s26AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFyycfU0_ + 644
    7   AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest          0x0000000100002b8d $s26AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFyycfU0_TA + 13
    8   AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest          0x00000001000025dd $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 45
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010034fe7c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100350f1b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100363a06 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 816
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001003642da _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 125
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003ca0b7 _pthread_wqthread + 583
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003c9e01 start_wqthread + 13
)
2019-07-24 12:25:40.718570+0100 AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest[1852:21340] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'player started when engine not running'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2d017cfd __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff576bea17 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2d032a1a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff291f2304 _Z19AVAE_RaiseExceptionP8NSStringz + 156
    4   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff29247d8c _ZN21AVAudioPlayerNodeImpl9StartImplEP11AVAudioTime + 1282
    5   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff29246b48 -[AVAudioPlayerNode play] + 75
    6   AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest          0x0000000100002924 $s26AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFyycfU0_ + 644
    7   AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest          0x0000000100002b8d $s26AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFyycfU0_TA + 13
    8   AVAudioPlayerNodeSwiftTest          0x00000001000025dd $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 45
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010034fe7c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100350f1b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100363a06 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 816
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001003642da _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 125
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003ca0b7 _pthread_wqthread + 583
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003c9e01 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Again, no problem if using the WONDERBOOM or built in speaker.

People are also having a problem here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118459

AudioKit also crashes: [AudioKit macOS HelloWorld crashes with UE BOOM 2 speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004135/audiokit-macos-helloworld-fails-with-ue-boom-2-speaker)

`AVAudioPlayer` is not sufficient for the application I am developing. What is the problem? Presumably since it throws an exception, it is a bug in Apple code?

Comment: @matt It is real code in a swift playground so does not require methods. It plays the audio fine except when the UE Boom 2 speaker is connected. Not production code, sure, but it is executing code.

Comment: I have a xamarin.mac app where the problem first manifested. Please assume (I believe it to be a safe assumption) that this problem is not due to the code executing in a playground.

Comment: People seem to be having a similar problem here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/118459

Comment: According to the documentation `AVAudioEngine.start()` calls `prepare`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioengine/1387024-start

Comment: I've updated the question to include a Swift macOS Cocoa app. This also crashes under the same circumstances.