# Know when NSException is thrown from Xamarin

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have some Xamarin.Mac code that calls a native function [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092434/avaudioplayer-play-works-but-avaudioplayernode-play-fails). When the function is called it sometimes causes an NSException to be thrown (dependent on connected hardware). Unfortunately the exception isn't caught using try/catch and it crashes my app.

For now I can live with the circumstances that give rise to the exception. However, I cannot live with my app crashing.

I wish to be able to trap when an NSException is thrown, perhaps report an error and continue.

Something like the following would do it:

```
ExceptionCatcher.CatchExceptionAndGetError(
    () => _platformThing.SometimesThrowException(),
    out var error);

if (error != null)
{
    // Report error
}

// Carry on
```

I have verified that the exception can be caught when using Objective-C directly.

I am aware of the NSException wrapping solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454808/3051702). However, before attempting to implement something like this to work with my code, is there something that already exists for Xamarin that I can use to handle this situation?

Comment: Yes, adding a `ObjCRuntime.Runtime.MarshalObjectiveCException` handler and using `MarshalObjectiveCExceptionMode.ThrowManagedException` gives me an exception I can handle such that my app no longer crashes. You utter, utter beauty. Thank you. You want to post this as an answer?

Comment: I'm keen to learn and improve. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Runtime.MarshalManagedException` and `Runtime.MarshalObjectiveCException` events can be used to intercept those exceptions.

Since capturing those exceptions is not performance free features, you have to enable them via the build process (mtouch/mmp):

- `--marshal-managed-exceptions=`

  - default
  - unwindnativecode
  - throwobjectivecexception
  - abort
  - disable
- `--marshal-objectivec-exceptions=`

  - default
  - unwindmanagedcode
  - throwmanagedexception
  - abort
  - disable

Xamarin has a Exception Marshaling detailed guide that covers both Xamarin.iOS & Mac:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/exception-marshaling